# ThisWorkbook.Activate is not working correctly at all computers

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

In `Book1.xlsb` in `ThisWorkbook` module I have a simple code:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
ThisWorkbook.Activate
MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

which activate Book1 workbook after opening.
If another book, for example `Book0` has been opened first, after opening `Book1` this book (Book1) becomes active, MessageBox appear in front of Book1 and Book1 remains active after macro execution. That is, the macro works as intended on most computers.

However, on some computers the code is executed, but Book1 does not become active, the previously opened book remains active. Only if I make `'MsgBox ThisWorkbook.Name` row commented — it helps, Book1 becomes active.
What could be the reason and how can I get the macro to work correctly on all computers?

Comment: You activate the workbook that is already active. Because that's what you say with the code `ThisWorkbook.Activate`. So the line makes no sense at all. If you want to activate another workbook, you have to address it by name. If it is not a fixed name, then you have to save the name in a variable before opening another workbook. You can then use this variable to access the previous workbook again. Just as a hint: In most cases commands like `activate` and `select` are not necessary.

Comment: It is `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`. Why would you make it public? This behavior should be related to some event code that is set up either in the open workbook or in an add-in e.g. if you use `Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate(): Me.Activate: End Sub` in the first workbook, the second will never become active. This is of course an extreme case that is not applicable here because without the message box your code works, but should give you an idea of what to look for e.g. if this behavior doesn't occur when the first wb is a new workbook, then you have localized it to the previous first wb...